# Material-designUse material-design with vue-router cause effect fail?

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-router, material-design-lite

Here is my `App.vue` code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'material-design-lite'
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus">
@import url('./assets/css/material-icons.css');
@import url('./assets/css/material.indigo-blue.min.css');
</style>
```

I use `Material-design-lite` package in my `vue.js` project.

Also I use `vue-router`

After I run `npm run dev`, the first page has material effect well, but when I change the url with `vue-router`, the basic css style still work, but the animate effect fail.

But I fresh the website, the animate effect works well.

I know the animate effect is came with `import 'material-design-lite'`

so, how can I make all the pages do well wit animate effect?

Comment: why don't you use the [vue-material](http://vuematerial.io/#/)?
It is a material design for vue. :)

Comment: @LakiGeri I'm using this now. But I still feel confused with before question. :)

Comment: @LakiGeri I found the reason https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic here it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun mdl componentHandler because vue templates are not mounted yet when it migth run. I used component "extends" to use this trick on every components I had.
See [Using material design with VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448649/using-material-design-with-vuejs).

```
<script>
    export default {
      name: 'Page',
      mounted: function () {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        componentHandler.upgradeDom()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()
      }
    }
</script>
//another component
<script>
export default {
    name: 'anotherComponent',
    extends: PageBase,
    ...
}
</script>
```